# Experience Editor always asks to save after adding workflow comments

Tags: experience-editor, workflow

When I add comment to the workflow transitioning from one state to another.  Experience editor always asks to save the page as shown below:
[image]

Is there a way not to show this pop-up? 
Or Can this be done?

Comment: Before you add the comment to the workflow, do you save your changes first?

Comment: Yes, there  are no pending change on the page.

Comment: Do you add any comments into the popup text box? You can suppress it by going to the Workflow item and checking the "Suppress Comment" checkbox.

Comment: @Gabbar yes, I added the comment and I need that functionality.

Comment: Are you updating any items/renderings when transitioning between states?

Comment: @Gabbar  I am not making any changes to the page. Just adding the comment asks me to reload the page.

Comment: Ok let me ask a different way, when you click on the option to move an item from one state to the next, do you have any custom code that's running and trying to update any items/renderings on the page?

Comment: @Gabbar no there is no custom code running after moving from one state to next.